# MVC Dataannotations Display attribute - replace text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to replace/append text to a display attribute from a model?

Here is the class property and I want to replace (Name) with the bank account holder name,

```
[Display(Name = "Hello, (Name)")]
public string Propertyname { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't like this idea, why don't you just add the text on the page

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only use constants as arguments to attributes so I'm not sure there is a way to achieve this with the `Display` attribute.  You may be able to use the `DisplayFormat` attribute and the `DataFormatString` of that attribute to achieve the desired affect.  Otherwise, you could create a custom attribute.

However, @Kyle raises a valid point and an attribute may not be the most appropriate place for this and something like

```
Hello, @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PropertyName)
```

would be better.